# Core data don't return full objects, data: <fault>

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

I'm trying to fetch two entities eg: Student with `email` `attribute` and Professor, both of have same parent entity eg: Person with `attributes` `entityId, firstName and lastName` i want to generate them in two sections using `NSFetchedResultsController`.
Here is a part from getter for `fetchedResultsController`

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];
[fetchRequest setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO];

NSEntityDescription *description = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Person"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:description];

NSSortDescriptor *firstNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *lastNameDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[firstNameDescriptor, lastNameDescriptor]];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                                         initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                         managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                           sectionNameKeyPath:@"entityId"
                                                                    cacheName:nil];
```

All `Students` have the same `entityId` and all `Professors` too

In tableView I have two prototype cells one for `Student` and another for `Professor`.
[image: It looks smth like this]

I get two sections as expected but students are in different sections, i have printed all objects from `fetchedResultsController` in console like this, `po [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:1]]` all professors are printed with `fault`:

```
<Professor: 0x6080000befc0> (entity: Professor; id: 0xd0000000001c0002 <x-coredata://03A3ECAD-CCA7-424E-86F9-258D25372BA1/Professor/p7> ; data: <fault>)
```

I have forced the fetch request to return full objects using `[request setReturnsObjectsAsFaults:NO]` but it had no effect.

Why is it happening so?

Comment: What happens if you try to get the value of one of the attributes of those objects, instead of just printing the object?

Comment: It is normal that core data doesn't load all data until you actually try to use any field of the fetched entity.

Comment: If i print them in code NSLog(@"%@", profesor.firstName); it prints

Comment: Ok, but the problem is when i try to access an object from fetchedResultsController i can get a student as well as a professor for the same section

Comment: That's because you specify "Person" as entity name. So it fetches all of Person's subclasses

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7304350/3985749) for an explanation of faults.  To separate students from professors, you need to add `entityId` as another (the first) sort descriptor.

Comment: But I use entityId, for all Student's is "1" and for all Professor's is "2"

Comment: Exactly - you need to sort by entityId to ensure that Students are separated from the Professors.  Currently your sort descriptors specify firstName and lastName.  So Professor **Charlie Dean** will come after Student **Alex Brown** but before Student **Eli Frost**.  Hence the mixing.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid "data fault" issue you should set this field of NSFetchRequest:

```
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
```

To separate students from professors in two sections you can use multiple NSFetchedResultsControllers, as described here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2309855/1689376

To avoid duplication of your code, just create a method like this and call it twice:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController) createFetchedResultsController: (NSString *)  entityName {
 //move your code here
}
```